# Blazor Preview 9 Issue with Logger in Razor Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

Since upgrading to `Net Core 3.0 Preview 9` I have been getting the following error when trying inject my console logger;

> WASM: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync(string,object[])
>
> WASM:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine] (TStateMachine& stateMachine) <0x2df6378 + 0x0003e> in :0
>
> WASM:   at Blazor.Extensions.Logging.BrowserConsoleLogger.Log[TState] (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel logLevel, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId eventId, TState state, System.Exception exception, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] formatter) <0x2df5e90 + 0x00094> in <3eb34b93cd4a47bf804fb0648b089edf>:0
>
> WASM:   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger, System.Exception exception) <0x2df51a0 + 0x00058> in :0
>
> WASM:   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Action`2[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger,System.Exception].invoke_void_T1_T2(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger,System.Exception)
>
> WASM:   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggingExtensions.UserAuthorizationFailed (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger) <0x2dee5f0 + 0x00014> in <85acc2b572f448f39259eac9936732f8>:0
>
> WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal user, System.Object resource, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] requirements) <0x2ddd378 + 0x00338> in <85acc2b572f448f39259eac9936732f8>:0
>
> WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.IsAuthorizedAsync (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal user) <0x2d52860 + 0x00228> in <5266bbb196bb40a89b886a09631725e6>:0
>
> WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync () <0x2d512a0 + 0x0026c> in <5266bbb196bb40a89b886a09631725e6>:0
>
> WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x2e0b8f0 + 0x00118> in :0
>
> WASM:   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x2bbb2e8 + 0x00248> in :0

In my razor view I inject the logger as follows;

```
@inject ILogger<Index> logger
```

My base `_Imports.razor` is as follows;

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@using Blazored.LocalStorage
@using Blazorise
@using Blazorise.Sidebar
```

and my `App.razor` is;

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <p>Nope, nope!</p>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Now the view being rendered at this point is a login page. Which is moved to on a redirect if the user is not authorized. So in my `MainLayout.Razor` page I have the following;

```
@functions
{
    [CascadingParameter] 
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            UriHelper.NavigateTo(@"\login");
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness the `ConfigureServices` in my `Startup.cs` adds the logger as follows;

```
        services.AddLogging(builder => builder
           .AddBrowserConsole() 
           .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
       );
```

Can anyone advise me what I am doing wrong here? As the 'login' page is rendering, it just seems to be the logger where the issue lies?

Per Tsengs comment my nuget dependencies are as follows;

[image: blazor dependencies]

Comment: Does this still happen if you disable the linker?

Comment: To confirm , I have just tried this and yes it still occurs with the linker disabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you are mixing versions (preview8 and preview9) in your projects or have a (third party) dependency on a library which is built against `preview8`.

In preview 9 `IJSRuntime` has signatures changed from `Task<T>` to `ValueTask<T>`

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/

> - Update implementations of IJSRuntime to return ValueTask.

In case of third party libraries, upgrade to newest version or wait till the developer of the library updates it.

Comment: Thanks Tseng, I've updated to include my dependencies? As far asI can see all looks ok?

Comment: Ok if I `[Inject] protected ILogger<Login> logger {get;set;}` tot he `@code` section of the Razor view , as opposed to `@inject Logger<Login> logger` at the top of the error disappears?

Comment: I don't see the dependencies of `Blazorize`, `Blazored` and `Blazor.Extension.Logging`. One of them **may** pull in older dependencies (not all projects / third party libraries update their packages at the same pace

Comment: I've updated to show the dependencies, but all looks ok, as I mentioned the above does solve the issue but I am unsure why?

Comment: Odd. You can try search `preview8` in the solution explorer, it could highlight any preview8 packages drawn from somewhere else (like in referenced projects, if any). The error message itself is pretty clear where the issue lies `System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync(string,object[])` which expects to find `Task` but new ones use `ValueTask`. Maybe some caching of the WASM runtime? clear nuget cache, retry use "Rebuild Solution"